# Keeping oracle connection alive, accessing oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

I have a JSP application that connects to oracle on the log in page.  How can I keep this connection alive and execute queries from it on another page?

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + HOST + ":1521:fcprod", request.getParameter("username"), request.getParameter("password"));
```

Comment: The best thing is you implement the design pattern [**Model–view–controller**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep connections alive using [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) which does connection pooling. It has commands to keep the connections alive when not in use. I use this in grails apps (similar to jsp) and hibernate based applications.

The above comment is correct though, you'll want to move the connection information out of the pages into a controller (not a great idea) or a service (probably the best idea).

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely not the way to go. Try implementing another solution because as i see it you are trying to shoot your own feet.

If you are using an application server that support pooled connections try making use of that. If not, try opening and closing connections in separate requests. If you want to keep open connections to the db during an open session that will quickly wipe out all your resources as the number of session grows. Trying to keep a single connection open during the lifetime of your application is even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good practice to have such scenario.
But you can store this con object into session scope using 
session.setAttribute("con", con);
and on whichever page you require, use
Connection con = (Connection)session.getAttribute("con");